# Кастомизация 2D персонажа в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Сразу стоит сказать что в Unity и C# я новичок.

Решил для практики создать 2D персонажа, анимировать его и сделать кастомизацию.
Нарисовал в Photoshop, каждую часть тела на отдельном слое + части одежды (тоже все по слоям).
Сохранил в формате PSB и закинул в Unity. п.с. в файле голый персонаж и один комплект одежды для него (все на отдельных слоях).
В Sprite Editor на вкладке Skinning Editor добавил персонажу и одежде кости, настроил их по слоям.
Сделал две анимации (простой и ходьбы).

Дальше стал вопрос как менять одежду. Сделал так что при нажатии на Q спрайт одежды (например шапки) меняется на другой спрайт из другого PSB файла, а на E обратно одевается первая шапка.
Одежда при нажатии на кнопки меняется, но вот анимации у второго комплекта одежды нет. То есть при движении головы вторая шапка просто висит на месте, вместо того чтоб двигаться вместе с головой.
Как это исправить? Или может есть другой способ осуществить кастомизацию?

Вообще изначально я рассматривал три способа анимации и кастомизации.

Первый описан выше. Мне он удобен благодаря костям с помощью которых легко анимировать, но столкнулся со сложностью кастомизации.

Второй способ который я рассматривал это просто закинуть спрайты персонажа и одежды (по частям), собрать их в Unity и анимировать каждый спрайт отдельно двигая и поворачивая его. Способ мне кажется очень не удобным, так как для того чтоб собрать персонажа в таком виде в каком его рисовал достаточно долго, да и способ анимации оооочень не удобный (по крайней мере для меня). Но при этом спрайты легко меняются и при переодевании во второй комплект одежды она (одежда) двигается вместе с персонажем.

Третий способ: нарисовать или собрать персонажа в другой программе (например Moho она же бывшая Anime Studio). Анимировать в ней персонажа и потом сохранить анимацию покадрово каждой части тела (без одежды, а потом и с одеждой) отдельно. Все это дело закинуть в Unity, собрать персонажа и сделать покадровую анимацию и когда требуется заменить спрайт (например) головы на спрайт головы с шапкой. В плане анимации этот вариант легкий, но получится ооочень много спрайтов и в них будет очень легко запутаться да и в целом способ достаточно сомнительный на мой взгляд.

Кстати, еще думал как решить проблему в первом способе и была мысль о том чтоб и персонажа и все комплекты одежды рисовать и переносить в Unity в одном файле PSB и те части одежды которые не должны отображаться просто скрыть, сделать невидимыми или что-то в этом духе. А когда нужно будет сменить одежду, то не менять спрайты, а отключать/скрывать уже одетые и включать/отображать нужные. Но тогда если я захочу добавить новый комплект одежды, то не смогу этого сделать. Нужно будет закидывать новый PSB, заново делать кости, анимацию и т.д.

Надеюсь не сильно запутано изложил мысли, попытался расписать достаточно подробно что делал. Может есть другие способы кастомизации.
В идеале решить проблему в первом способе (когда при замене спрайта новый спрайт не двигается), но если нет, то может кто-то подскажет другой способ или хоть в каком направлении копать.

Может и анимировать и кастомизировать можно в Spine или Dragon Bones Pro?

Answer (score 0):

Сам спросил сам и отвечу.

Если использовать первый способ (с файлом PSB).

1. Рисуем персонажа в Photoshop (или рисуйте где удобно (например в Paint Tool SAI) но потом нужно экспортировать в Photoshop. Голого и один комплект одежды (можно больше). Все на разных слоях. Слои отсортировать в нужном порядке. Например: (сверху вниз) правый рукав, правая рука, правая штанина, правая нога, шапка, голова, одежда на теле, тело, левая штанина, левая нога, левый рукав, левая рука. Отключаем слой с фоном и сохраняем в формате PSB.
2. Закидываем этот файл в Unity. Клацаем на файл, заходим в Sprite Editor, далее переходим в Skinning Editor. Создаем кости и соединяем их с нужными слоями.
3. Переносим персонажа в сцену и делаем с ним все что нужно (анимируем, пишем ему код и все такое)
4. Если нужно добавить новый комплект одежды, то открываем папку с проектом, находим PSB файл персонажа и открываем его в Photoshop.
5. Рисуем новую одежду прямо в этом файле или можно нарисовать в другом файле/программе, а потом перекинуть нужные слои. Сохраняем.
6. Переходим в Unity и видим что новая одежда добавилась, теперь ей нужно назначить кости. Заходим в Sprite Editor, потом в Skinning Editor и назначаем.
7. Ненужную в данный момент одежду скрываем. (как скрыть/показать объекты в Unity думаю найдете).

Вот и все, таким образом можно добавлять новую одежду, части тела, оружие и т.д.

Единственная проблема это то что если из персонажа сделать префаб, то в префаб новая одежда не добавляется. Но думаю эту проблему можно решить как-то. Если найду способ, то напишу.

Решил и эту проблему. Сначала создаем пустой объект в Unity, а потом В него перетягиваем файл с персонажем. Делаем префаб. В этом случае когда файл PSB будет обновляться, то и префаб тоже обновится.

Писал в основном для себя чтоб не забыть, но может кому тоже пригодится.